# Information from Topic Visualization to a text file?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible to get information from "Topic Visualization" tool to a text file. For example I want to take values in "gazebo/default/pose/info" topic. Alternatively, can I take this information using c++ and ros ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12822/information-from-topic-visualization-to-a-text-file-?/) by [Zuygar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2506/zuygar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could echo whatever is being published to the topic from the command line and direct that to a file, for example:

```
gz topic -e /gazebo/default/pose/info > ~/test.txt
```

Programmatically, you can setup a simple Gazebo subscriber (note this is not a ROS subscriber) which writes to a file, see [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=topics_subscribed&cat=transport) tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1